# How to allow ssl in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, https, ssl-certificate

I have the following code in my htacess which I believe is conflicting with https because it keeps redirecting to http

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mysite.com [nc]
  rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```

Does anyone know how I can stop the https redirecting and keep it https if thats what has been entered?

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to "https" instead of "http":

```
rewritecond %{http_host} ^mysite.com [nc]
  rewriterule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
```